# Receive error: undefined reference to static member while I have defined them in classname.cpp

Tags: c++11, static

I am trying to define static members in a class and always received error undefined reference to static members.

I realize there are already many similar questions.  But It seems that in those questions errors are raised because they did not define static members somewhere outside the class.  I am sure that I have defined these static members.

The following is the problematic part of my code.

In foo.h, I defined a class named foo.

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
class foo
{
public:
int random = dist(mt);
static std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 mt;
static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
static std::vector<int> ans(const int &);
};
```

In foo.cpp, there are definitions of static members.

```
#include<random>
#include<vector>
#include "foo.h"
std::random_device foo::rd;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> foo::dist(0, 10);
std::mt19937 foo::mt(rd());
std::vector<int> foo::ans(const int & size) {
    std::vector<int> bb;
    for(int i=0; i < size; ++i)
        bb.push_back(dist(mt));
    return bb;
}
```

I used the class in another cpp file named test.cpp

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
    foo a;
    std::vector<int> c=a.ans(5);
    for(auto it=c.begin(); it!=c.end(); ++it)
            std::cout<<*it<<"\t";
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

With `g++ test.cpp -o a.out`, I always received:

```
/tmp/ccUPnAxJ.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `foo::ans(int const&)' 
/tmp/ccUPnAxJ.o: In function `foo::foo()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN3fooC2Ev[_ZN3fooC5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `foo::mt'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN3fooC2Ev[_ZN3fooC5Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `foo::dist'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status'
```

My g++ version is: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, and `g++` is an alias to `g++ -std=c++11`.

Comment: You don't build with the `foo.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
g++ test.cpp foo.cpp -o a.out
```

Otherwise, how would `g++` know about `foo.cpp` at all?  It doesn't magically guess based on seeing `#include "foo.h"`.

Comment: Well, I thought it would do this automatically. I misunderstood it. Thanks.